# PHP Redeclare error when using .htaccess auto_prepend_file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mysqli, wamp

I have a file called `config.php` in which I include different files with functions in them, using `require_once`.
When I try to auto prepend `config.php` using `.htaccess` stored in the project root, I get a redeclare error in every file that has functions in it.

Is there a way of fixing this or including `config.php` without getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured a solution using `foreach` and `glob`. I don't know if it's efficient or not, but it seems to work.

```
// Include all files in X directory
foreach (glob('X\*.php') as $file)
{
    $script = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $filename = basename($file);
    if ($script != $filename)
    {
        include_once $file;
    }
}
```

This code is in the auto prepended file.